# How to add local account of another computer to sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2005, iis, dotnetnuke

I need to add a user (\network_service) to a different computer's sql server logins.
How can I do this?  I am attempting to search for the account, but it is not finding it.
In SQL Server:

```
Security >
Right-Click Logins >
Click "Search" >
attempt to find \\<computername>\network_service
attempt to find \\<computername.domainname>\network_service
attempt to find <computername>\network_service
```

...nothing is working.  I am searching under "all locations".
This is to get a dotnetnuke website running with using a separate server for its sql database.  Supposedly, I need to add the NETWORK_SERVICE account as a sql server login.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please pay more attention to your tags - you've been around here long enough to know better.

Comment: Connect multiple words with hyphens.  As it was, you had `2005` as a tag by itself, which is meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647402.aspx

Network Service on one computer is Network Service on all; It is a limited-privilege, authenticatable user account common to all Windows NT machines. So, you should be able to simply grant the DB server's Network Service user access to the DB, and then applications, whether local or remote, that are authenticating themselves as Network Services should get the same access.

Comment: The Network Service account's credentials are of the form DomainName\AspNetServer$, where DomainName is the domain of the ASP.NET server and AspNetServer is your Web server name.
...this worked!  thanks very much.